# changing post contents

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a file called: index.php, in which I have a form and within that form i got ajax code in which I do a call to a PHP file. This external PHP file will generate hidden input fields which will later on be appended in to my form.

This is the ajax code:

```
$urlforXmltoHtml = "xmltohtml.php";
$.get($urlforXmltoHtml,
  { uniquekey: Reference },
  function (data) {
    $("#Data").append(data);
    $('#msform').submit();
});
```

This is the div in the index.php where the generated hidden fields will be appended to:

```
 <div id="Data">
 </div>
```

In the xmltohtml.php i got this:

```
<?php

session_start();
$xml="";
//gebruik uniquekey van cops.php
$uniquekey = $_GET['uniquekey'];
if (file_exists('downloads/'.$uniquekey.'.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('downloads/'.$uniquekey.'.xml');
    foreach( $xml as $headItems )
      {

        foreach($headItems as $item){
          $_SESSION['count'] = $_SESSION['count'] + 1;
          $count =   $_SESSION['count'];
          echo '<div style="display:none;">';
          //preg replaces successive space characters
          $description = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $item->->Description);
          //encoding http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php
                 echo '<input type="hidden" name="DESCRIPTION['.$count.']" value="'. htmlspecialchars($description, ENT_QUOTES) .'">';
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="-QUANTITY['.$count.']" value="'. htmlspecialchars($item->Quantity,ENT_QUOTES) .'">';
          echo '</div>';
        }
      }
} else {

  exit('Failed to open xml.' . $uniquekey);
}
?>
```

but now as input when I got a $description for example witth item& then if i copy paste the html code from out chrome's element inspector I see it will be changed to item$amp; and actually when I post, I just want to post item& and not `item&amp;`.

any idea how I could change this so it will send `&` and not `&amp;`, or does it just send `&`?

Comment: Can't you just use regex to identify &amp; and replace with &?

Comment: W3validator recommends sending `;&amp`, just saying

Comment: could you post me a link for that description? thank you

Comment: Please provide all your code in the question, not as a pastebin (those might vanish and then the question gets useless). Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't send URL parameters by concatenating them to the URL, but by sending them as the `data` parameter to jQuery's `$.get`:

```
$urlforXmltoHtml = "xmltohtml.php";
$.get($urlforXmltoHtml,
  { uniquekey: Reference },
  function (data) {
    $("#Data").append(data);
    $('#msform').submit();
});
```

On a side note, what you're doing here is **very** dangerous:

```
$uniquekey = $_GET['uniquekey'];
if (file_exists('downloads/'.$uniquekey.'.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('downloads/'.$uniquekey.'.xml');
```

**Never** trust input from the client! In this case, you should whitelist a set of keys and only use those to retrieve/manipulate files on the server.

Comment: thanks for the useful info Marcel, but when the input fields are generated i see as input value for example value="item1&item2" if i copy this from the chrome inspector and paste it for example in a notepad then I get: value="item1&amp;item2"   if i post this the receiving party will get an error on the & so i think they receive $amp;

Comment: @bboni It is correct that ampersands are encoded as `&amp;` when sending them as part of a URL parameter. The server will correctly decode them.

Comment: @bboni You're using `html_entity_decode("test1&amp;test2")` when outputting the HTML. Please use `htmlspecialchars` when outputting variables to a form, like `htmlspecialchars("test1&test2")` (also that `count` variable). Always use the correct encoding function **when outputting** some text.

Comment: yes I already used that, as I can see this is an old upload of my PHP, thanks :) So if you do a form POST all the characters like & will be correctly encoded and sent like $amp; which is the correct way ?

Comment: @bboni Yes, when doing a *normal* form post (without using JavaScript), characters are always correctly encoded. When using jQuery's AJAX methods and correctly use the `data` parameter like I described, URL parameters will be correctly encoded. There should be no need to use helper functions like `urldecode` on the server side, unless you're doing something the wrong way.

Comment: @bboni Looking at your new PHP code now, I can see you're not using `htmlspecialchars` in *every* instance, the second and third field lack those function calls. And you shouldn't pass `&amp;` to `htmlspecialchars`, unless you want *that* exact string in your form, of course. And, again, you should really check the validity of the `uniquekey` parameter, as attackers will be able to get files from your server you don't want them to see!

Comment: that is just temporary and the files are temporary not so confidential :) I changed all to htmlspecialchars but these input fields will not be inserted with an &amp; but with just & so for example item1&3254 can be insterted as description

Comment: @bboni Really, security shouldn't be an afterthought, something you apply after everything works, you might easily oversee something crucial. E.g., the output of `$count` is not encoded. I guess you do not actually need `htmlspecialchars` here, as it is a plain number, but it is a good habit to *always* properly encode your output.

Answer (score 0):

Use urldecode() on PHP:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.urldecode.php

Or decodeURIComponent() on Javascript:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent